# How to animate a line-stroke property in MapBox GL

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to add a style property to a line that invokes flow. For example, a flowing river or a fiber optic line carrying data. Can anyone suggest how to create this sort of effect on a line in MapBox-GL-JS? Maybe this could be accomplished will a transitionable fill-pattern?

```
'paint': {
        'line-width': 3
    }
```

Comment: like https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/281#issuecomment-263955782 ?

Comment: @andrewharvey - yep that's what I am thinking. Any idea how to emulate the mapzen example in GL?